# Error ITMS-90168: "The binary you uploaded was invalid."

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, watchos

I am trying to upload an application to the App Store. It contains a watchOS 2 app, watchOS "1" extension, and a few iOS extensions. I cannot figure out why this is happening. When I use the "Upload to App Store…" feature of Xcode 7 (or use Application Loader), I get the message "Archive submission failed with errors:" with the error being "ERROR ITMS-90168: 'The binary you uploaded was invalid.'"

Has anyone else run into this issue? Any suggestions?

Comment: I have the same issue with an iPhone app (no watch extension)..

Comment: Maybe this can help someone to figure out what is wrong. It's the log from the Application Loader that I get when uploading the app through Xamarin: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/0391458c8e23f350e325 I have the exact same issue if I upload an app through XCode, but don't know how to get the log there..

Comment: Turned out to be something wrong with installations on my machine (probably XCode or OS X update). I just tried it on a different machine and it works fine there.

Comment: Here you can find a solution for my particular case. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32908964/error-itms-90168-the-binary-you-uploaded-was-invalid

Comment: check it apps version...

Answer (score 2):

Because you've already uploaded another app version to the store, now you'll need to create a new version and upload that.

Comment: Hi Meng, welcome to Stack. Quickly: if you expand your answer to include any additional information / make it clearer (also for any future readers in a few years time) you'll help make / keep Stack a premium resource for all us geeks, and you'll get more upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a problem when there is an app extension with the same name as the other builds on test flight for the app. If you're seeing this problem, you can try renaming one of those so that they have distinct names. There may be probability, we got the solution with that.

Answer (score 0):

You are far from being alone here.

> https://forums.developer.apple.com/search.jspa?q=90168

Looks like some kind of Xcode issue, because hundreds of people are getting the same error. I guess we have to wait for the Xcode patch to solve this issue.

Comment: nothing helps. bugreport says that they cant reproduce it. So I'm stuck. Thinking of reinstalling os x, xcode and ios..... :(

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to submit using application loader but no success with versions 3.0 or 3.1. Then I downloaded the lastest version (3.6) which can be downloaded only with xcode, after hours with that version I had success.

Comment: From where you downloaded version 3.6?