# Error ITMS-90168: “The binary you uploaded was invalid.”

Tags: xcode, app-store

During uploading binary to AppStore I receive an error:

**Error ITMS-90168: “The binary you uploaded was invalid.”**

I can't upload my binary. Nothing helps.
Tried creating new project. Tried uploading from another computer.
Have anybody succeeded in dealing with this issue?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Someone recommend check this link https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/17583

Answer (score 69, accepted):

```
cd ~/.itmstransporter
rm update_check*
mv softwaresupport softwaresupport.bak
cd UploadTokens
rm *.token
```

I tried in accordance with this method, but still reported the same mistake

Comment: Can you explain this a bit?

Comment: I read the logs of "application loader". I found that it use some content under .itmstransporter directory, then I tried to remove some file that generated by "application loader".  It Works! I guess this error was caused by some files leaved by previous failed uploading process.

Comment: omg.. i spent XX hours trying to debug this.. this finally saved my but! tnx bro!

Comment: This answer also worked for a similar error message: Error ITMS-90168: “”

Comment: I was getting "Could not make parent directory for: /Users/Myname/.itmstransporter/softwaresupport/bin/Frameworks/ITunesConnectFoundation.framework/Resources/Info.plist" and this fixed it! Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for this. I got the correct error message showing after using this solution.

Comment: This worked for me too. I've had problems the last few months just to upload binaries. I had to bring my secondary MacBook Pro just to upload binaries. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: I spent days trying to figure this crap out, i wish I could up vote a million times.

Comment: I'm having the same issue and I'm not able to build yet. Any suggestion?

Comment: Can you help me please? I'm having this issue yet and I don't know how can I solve it.

Comment: which file to delete?@wilesduan

Answer (score 72):

Lazy solution!!

I had downloaded Application Loader from a link in the iTunes Connect app submission page. This gave me version 3.0, where I ran into the error.

Instead you can go to Xcode, and open Application Loader from there, which gives version 3.6, where the problem magically disappeared.

You can find it from the top menu: Xcode -> Open Developer Tool -> Application Loader

[image]

Comment: For anyone who comes here this solution is far better and easier than the first although less up-voted.

Comment: THIS IS THE SOLUTION

Comment: Awesome !! Even till date this works for me. Thanks a ton

Comment: I had problem with all other above solution. But this solved my problem.

Comment: THIS!!!!!!! Ugh, as if the Apple development, build, and distribution process wasn't already confusing enough!

Comment: You are my hero

Comment: No longer works with Xcode 11 - Application loader has been removed, it seems.