# Xcode error ITMS-90168 "The binary you uploaded was invalid"

Tags: ios, xcode

I just updated Xcode (8.1), Application Loader (3.0). I tested my App in My iPhone 7 (iOS 10.1.1) and worked perfectly.

I validated it on Xcode and when I try to upload by Application Loader, the attached error is shown.

```
1 package(s) were not uploaded because they had problems:
/var/folders/f0/ty8cz9t14l7dmc3nqzt5l_xh0000gn/T/AB062B43-ADF0-47BA-A0CF-40353441CDAB/1167082332.itmsp - Error Messages:
    ERROR ITMS-90168: "The binary you uploaded was invalid."
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32620661/error-itms-90168-the-binary-you-uploaded-was-invalid

Comment: Check the email associated with your itunes connect account. The specific reason for the invalid binary should be there.

Comment: Try another mac to upload your app..  Check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/32987261/6847276

Comment: I tried both. None resolved! :(

Comment: There's a link in the other question. https://forums.developer.apple.com/search.jspa?q=90168
Apple making us mad

Comment: I developed it in Ionic 1.3

Comment: Try solution with similar error (ITMS 9000: The binary you upload was invalid) from the best answer from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24823926/itms-9000-the-binary-you-upload-was-invalid).

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the Aplication Loader; your version is old; uninstal Xcode and reinstall to get the last version and send again your app